# OctoberCMS or pure Laravel

Tags: laravel, frameworks, e-commerce, octobercms

I need to create a **web app (product/estimates configurator) + ecommerce + website** and I can't decide between **Laravel** or **OctoberCMS** + writing custom plugins.

I need to create **some static pages** (October would be great for those) and **a backend to manage estimates** for a single user (an independent contractor): I need to **interpolate data from a database of spare parts** and **calculate the final price including the labour cost**.

At the first stage the contractor will manage manually the customer care and will send the estimate to the applicant.

At a later stage the applicant would be able to buy a spare part from the web store bypassing the contractor (e.g., when he only needs a spare part and is able to install it by himself), so it will be a real **e-commerce platform.**

Can't really know if OctoberCMS can help me developing faster but will go against me when I'll need further customizations.

Has anyone been in the same situation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can totally go with `OctoberCMS` as you can see its built upon Laravel.

Pages will act as The controller and add `plugin components` for business logic. [ this will work same like controller/actions]

Also, you are able to add static content to pages. and use them as static HTML pages.

You can add Laravel components/packages to your plugin and directly use them like you use it in `Laravel`

and upon that, if you need to add some `RAW` Laravel functionality you can add that as well from the root directory, `artisan` console commander is there `composer` is there all config file is there so no issue there.

New OctoberCMS is based on `Laravel 5.5` so you have Plus point, it can support all latest 
packages as well.

You can add your custom controller and just use it like Laravel project.

So I would say using OctoberCMS will give you more functionalities.

- out of the box user session management [Plugins needed]
- static HTML pages
- Better List management of table data [Backend lists]
- Lots of Plugins
- Better Ajax support

If any other issue please comment.